# Bootstrap Font Awesome and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, fonts, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm using [Font Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome) for my project and it works fine for chrome, firefox and IE9 but it fails show icons for ie8. I tried if it was my fault but also the project site doesn't show fonts ony my IE8 (win7).

I use the default web-protection of IE8, what can be the reason ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fonts only work when viewed in IE8 mode (not compatibility or IE7 standards mode) so make sure that your browser is set to that mode. Further down on the [roadmap](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#roadmap) section of the page you can see where they list future support for IE7, which IE8 compat view should be emulating.

Comment: Full support for IE7+ has been added as of late May 2012.  Here is the (now closed) Issue on the project page: [IE 7 support for icons in bootstrap](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/38)

Answer (score 0):

1. Added this to htaccess. "BrowserMatch MSIE best-standards-support Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=8 env=best-standards-support"
2. trying to reconvert eot font
3. doc compactibility mode chnage
4. tried usleep function
5. setInterval js
6. add google html5 script
7. call css in body part for ie8
8. add data-icon class
9. ad pseudo elements js
10. add png & svg filters in css
11. check font type Permission in server

but finally works when added

> **.sass and .less css**

files